# iOS using self.tableview in block make retain Cycle So leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, block, tableview

in my `UITableViewController`'s loading Process, i fetch `UITableView`'s Data From ServerSingleton Class With Block, async network method

i give block, which Process `UITableView` reloadData when data fetch Done, to that method

```
 __weak typeof(MyTableViewController) *weakSelf = self;
 NSURLSessionTask *task = [[ServerSingleton getSharedServerModule] getPostsBestWithCategory:self.categoryNameString
                                                                                          numberOf:10
                                                                                    fromLastPostID:nil
                                                                                          andBlock:^(NSArray *posts_,
                                                                                                     NSError *error) {
                                                                                              if (!error) {

                                                                                                  weakSelf.posts=posts_;
                                                                                                  [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];   /////////Only This row make LEAK!!!!
                                                                                                  [weakSelf addFooterActivity];
                                                                                                  [weakSelf checkAndPlayWithContentOffset];

                                                                                              weakSelf.isLoadingMoreData=false;
                                                                                          }];
        [UIAlertView showAlertViewForTaskWithErrorOnCompletion:task delegate:nil];
        [headRefreshControl setRefreshingWithStateOfTask:task];
    }
```

and this below is ServerSingleTon's method and when network request done, it process block which i gave it before

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)getPostsBestWithCategory:(NSString *)categoryName                                
                                           numberOf:(NSInteger)number
                                     fromLastPostID:(NSString *)LastPostID
                                           andBlock:( void (^)(NSArray *posts,
                                                               NSError *error))block{

AFHTTPSessionManager *client=[self getSessionManagerForInsecureDNS];

NSString *urlStr=@"urlString";


return [client GET:urlStr
        parameters:nil
           success:^(NSURLSessionTask *__unused task,id json){
               NSArray *adaptedResult =[self PostArrayAdapterWithObject:json];
               if (block) {
                   block([NSArray arrayWithArray:adaptedResult],nil);
               }
           }
           failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *__unused task,NSError *error){
               if (block) {
                   block([NSArray array],error);
               }
           }];
```

my problem is that my custom `UITableView` controller get in retain Cycle thus cause leak.

I figure out my problem is using self in block, so i change it to weakSelf, But It leaks too, and it was because of  calling `[weakSelf.tableView reloadData];`

when i delete this, it doesn't leak , but when the line exist it make retain cycle and leak

what make leaks only to access `UITableView`? but others not????

i have tried using weak type of `UITableView` itself, 
and `UITableView` is initiated from nib so i connect With `__weak` property

Answer (score 3):

Just solving the same problem, you might want to check your code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, `self` is probably retained somewhere in the `UITableViewCell` code, since the only difference is the `[tableView reloadData]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `[UITableView reloadData]` from a non-main thread, and this may be the cause of the leak you are seeing:

```
if (!error) {
    weakSelf.posts=posts_;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    });                      
    ...
```

You may want to use `dispatch_sync()` in the above code, depending on what those methods after it do, or you may want to add them into dispatched block.

Comment: No, it was not the case, the completion block was already perform in  main dispatch queue. So nothing was changed at all.